# access all locations of canvas HTML 5 map using selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas

Hello I have been trying to access all the points (counties) of a canvas map. The approach I am using is to find the center point of the map and crawl through the rest of the points (counties) using the move_by_offset(x,y).perform() method. This is becoming difficult as the code will always start from the center and will give an error if offset is falling outside of the map. I am having this issue because the map boundaries are not defined and there's no tag for any of the points on the map. Below is the code I am using

```
enter code here

 s=[]

 driver.maximize_window() 
 canvas = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("canvas")[4]
 time.sleep(5)
 hover=action.move_to_element(canvas)
 hover.perform()

 box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'flourish-popup-content')]") #to 
 access the tooltip information
 s.append(box.text)
```

#Above code will give the tooltip information of the county at the center

#To access other locations

```
enter code here
for i in range(500):

try:
    

action.move_by_offset(-5,-5).perform()
time.sleep(2)
box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'flourish-popup-content')]")
time.sleep(3)
if box.text not in s:
s.append(box.text)
else:
pass

except:
    pass
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you make sure your code is formatted properly?

Comment: for i in range(500):
    try:
        
    
        action.move_by_offset(-5,-5).perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'flourish-popup-content')]")
        time.sleep(3)
        if box.text not in s:
            s.append(box.text)
        else:
            pass

    except:
        pass

Comment: does it answer your question? Let me know if you need more information

Comment: The map that i want to scrape is this one https://flo.uri.sh/story/891697/embed?auto=1#slide-0